# Is opengl necessary for mobile game development?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, opengl-es

I am currently developing game for android & iphone & I want to know whether i should develop using frame by frame animation requiring lots of image sequence or use Opengl for creating animation?

What is more recommended in case of game development for manipulation of images?

Also for iphone what should i start with among various frameworks provided (Cocas2D, Core Animation, Core Image, Quartz etc)

Comment: Can you explain a bit better about the two options here? You can render different images with OpenGL just fine. So I don't see how it's a choice. Also, your second question is a separate question (and not a constructive one, since it's just an invitation for discussion).

Answer (score 5):

I will divide my answer into 3 sections: iOS, Android and Windows Phone, as these are the most common mobile operating systems.

## iOS

openGL is not necessary, unless you want to make high-performance games.
This means, you can draw simple 2d stuff by software (cpu), but you will not be able to draw
awesome 3d worlds (ego shooter, 3d racing games and so on.) or 2d games with too complex effects. On newer iOS versions (don't remember the actual version) 2d ui stuff is also hardware accelerated. For using opengl you should make use of a third party library such as those you mentioned.

## Android

Here mostly the same as on iOS applies - You don't need to use opengl but if you do you do have more possibilities in complexity, graphics and flexibility.

Till Android 3.0 (API 11) you are able to enable hardware acceleration even for 2d canvas graphics.

## Windows Phone 7

Here you definitely will not use opengl. What? No awesome games in wp7?
Heh, of course, it's name is Direct3D 9. It's the MS pendant to the opensource opengl.
Direct3d is, in short, much easier to use, has a lot more features and proves mostly better performance. And all that, even direct3d 9 is a bit outdated, current version is 11.1, which is really awesome. Im neither a wp7 nor a windows fanboy, but direct3d just got simpler apis.
Additionally Visual Studio provides the best integration for developing games (XNA+VS).

## Misc

I've programmed on all three platforms, mainly on Android thus speaking:
Game development on Android is the most difficult on all three, because there is no direct support from the IDE and it quickly can get quiet awkward. I recommend using a 3rd party library, such as LibGDX, which I do.
Then comes iOS, which provides little support from XCode for game development.
And finally Windows Phone 7, where Visual Studio provides full fledged game development support.

## Conclusion

Finally said: For simple image manipulation (rotation, translation) you don't need openGL. For complex transistions, even if they are 2d, you really should use openGL. Personally, I won't ever make a game without hardware acceleration - because of performance and minor flexibility. You can't say what's coming in the future, yet!

Comment: "Direct3d is, in short, much easier to use, has a lot more features and proves mostly better performance".  This statement is false/debatable and one person's opinion.  I can point you to evidence to the contrary if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Frame-by-Frame animation is what I used for the iPhone game I wrote. As long as you don't have too many images (causing a lot of memory use and long load times), this method can be good.

But using 3D animations can be good too, if you have the means to produce the assets.

So the real answer to your question is, no it's not necessary to use 3D (I assume that's what you mean by OpenGL). But it might be a better way to go, depending on your needs.

On iPhone, I recommend Cocos2D as a framework, as it has a lot of nice features and is quite stable. This is not to say the others are bad. Just that Cocos is good. :)